# How is it possible that a function can call itself

Tags: recursion, lisp, computer-science, environment

I know about recursion, but I don't know how it's possible. I'll use the fallowing example to further explain my question.

```
(def (pow (x, y))
     (cond ((y = 0) 1))
           (x * (pow (x , y-1))))
```

The program above is in the Lisp language. I'm not sure if the syntax is correct since I came up with it in my head, but it will do. In the program, I am defining the function pow, and in pow it calls itself. I don't understand how it's able to do this. From what I know the computer has to completely analyze a function before it can be defined. If this is the case, then the computer should give an undefined message when I use pow because I used it before it was defined. The principle I'm describing is the one at play when you use an x in x = x + 1, when x was not defined previously.

Comment: it's not enough to add more parenthesis to python/ruby code, to get lisp code. sorry, this is not even close to lisp. next time provide example in language you know, recursion is not limited to lisp. on how it is implemented - it depends and it's huge topic. you can learn on of the ways from "An Introduction to Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus" by Greg Michaelson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilers are much smarter than you think.
A compiler can turn the recursive call in this definition:

```
(defun pow (x y)
  (cond ((zerop y) 1)
        (t (* x (pow x (1- y))))))
```

into a `goto` intruction to re-start the function from scratch:

```
Disassembly of function POW
(CONST 0) = 1
2 required arguments
0 optional arguments
No rest parameter
No keyword parameters
12 byte-code instructions:
0     L0
0     (LOAD&PUSH 1)
1     (CALLS2&JMPIF 172 L15)              ; ZEROP
4     (LOAD&PUSH 2)
5     (LOAD&PUSH 3)
6     (LOAD&DEC&PUSH 3)
8     (JSR&PUSH L0)
10    (CALLSR 2 57)                       ; *
13    (SKIP&RET 3)
15    L15
15    (CONST 0)                           ; 1
16    (SKIP&RET 3)
```

If this were a more complicated recursive function that a compiler cannot unroll into a loop, it would merely call the function again.

Answer (score 2):

> From what I know the computer has to completely analyze a function before it can be defined.

When the compiler sees that one defines a function POW, then it tells itself: now we are defining function POW. If it then inside the definition sees a call to POW, then the compiler says to itself: oh, this seems to be a call to the function that I'm currently compiling and it can then create code to make a recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

A function is just a block of code. It's name is just help so you don't have to calculate the exact address it will end up in. The programming language will turn the names into where the program is to go to execute.

How one function call another is by storing the address of the next command in this function on the stack, perhaps add arguments to the stack and then jump to the address location of the function. The function itself jumps to the return address it finds so that control goes back to the callee. There are several calling conventions implemented by the language on which side do what. CPUs don't really have function support so just like there is nothing called a while loop in CPUs functions are emulated.

Just like functions have names, arguments have names too, however they are mere pointers just like the return address. When calling itself it just adds a new return address and arguments onto the stack and jump to itself. The top of the stack will be different and thus the same variable names are unique addresses to the call so `x` and `y` in the previous call is somewhere else than the current `x` and `y`. In fact there is no special treatment needed for calling itself than calling anything else.

Historically the first high level language, Fortran, did not support recursion. It would call itself but when it returned it returned to the original callee without doing the rest of the function after the self call. Fortran itself would have been impossible to write without recursion so while itself used recursion it did not offer it to the programmer that used it.  This limitation is the reason why John McCarthy discovered Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

I think to see how this can work *in general*, and in particular in cases where recursive calls *can't* be turned into loops, it's worth thinking about how a general compiled language might work, because the problems are not different.

Let's imagine how a compiler might turn this function into machine code:

```
(defun foo (x)
  (+ x (bar x)))
```

And let's assume that it does not know anything about `bar` at the time of compilation.  Well, it has two options.

1. It can compile `foo` in such a way that the call to `bar` is translated a set of instructions which say, 'look up the function definition stored under the name `bar`, whatever it currently is, and arrange to call that function with the right arguments'.
2. It can compile `foo` in such a way that there is a machine-level function call to a function but the address of that function is left as a placeholder of some kind.  And it can then attach some metadata to `foo` which says: 'before this function is called you need to find the function named `bar`, find its address, splice it into the code in the right place, *and remove this metadata*.

Both of these mechanisms allow `foo` to be defined before it's known what `bar` is.  And note that instead of `bar` I could have written `foo`: these mechanisms deal with recursive calls too.  They differ apart from that, however.

- The first mechanism means that, every time `foo` is called it needs to do some kind of dynamic lookup for `bar` which will involve some overhead (but this overhead can be pretty small):

  - as a consequence of this the first mechanism will be slightly slower than it might be;
  - but, also as a consequence of this, if `bar` gets redefined, then the new definition will get picked up, which is a very desirable thing for an interactive language, which Lisp implementations usually are.
- The second mechanism means that, after `foo` has all its references to other functions linked in to it, then the calls happen at the machine level:

  - this means they will be quick;
  - but that redefinition will be, at best, more complicated or, at worst, not possible at all.

The second of these implementations is close to how traditional compilers compile code: they compile code leaving a bunch of placeholders with associated metadata saying what names those placeholders correspond to.  A *linker*, (sometimes known as a link-loader, or loader) then grovels over all the files produced by the compiler as well as other libraries of code and resolves all these references, resulting in a bit of code which can actually be run.

A very simple-minded Lisp system might work entirely by the first mechanism (I am pretty sure that this is how Python works, for instance).  A more advanced compiler will probably work by some combination of the first and second mechanism.  As an example of this, CL allows the compiler to make assumptions that apparent self-calls in functions really *are* self-calls, and so the compiler may well compile them as direct calls (essentially it will compile the function and then link it on the fly).  But when compiling code in general, it might call 'through the name' of the function.

There are also more-or-less heroic strategies which things could do: for instance at the first call of a function link it, on the fly, to all the things it refers to, and note in *their* definitions that if they change then this thing needs to be unlinked as well so it all happens again.  These kind of tricks once seemed implausible, but compilers for languages like JavaScript do things at least as hairy as this all the time now.

---

Note that compilers and linkers for modern systems actually do something more complicated than I've described, because of shared libraries &c: what I described is more-or-less what happened pre shared-library.